# Selecting Distinct using LINQ with CRM

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I am trying to Select Distinct set using a LINQ to CRM query and it continues to return dupilicate records. The query I am using is:

```
  var linqQuery = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                   join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") on ((EntityReference)r["accountid"]).Id equals c["accountid"]
                   join u in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("systemuser") on ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Id equals u["systemuserid"]
                   where (r["statuscode"].Equals("100000004") || r["statuscode"].Equals("100000003")) && r["statecode"].Equals("Open")
                   where u["internalemailaddress"].Equals(_currentUser.Email)

                       select new
                           {
                                 AccountId = !c.Contains("accountid") ? string.Empty : c["accountid"],
                                 Account = !c.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : c["name"]
                             }).Distinct();
```

Am I missing something to make `.Distinct()` work? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Is this CRM 2011 ? If so, you're better off querying entity sets (accountSet, opportunitySet, etc.) off OrganizationServiceProxy

Comment: `Distinct` simply uses the default equality comparer, which in turn uses `Object.Equals`, which again in turn is correctly overridden on anonymous classes and simply considers them equal if all properties are equal. So basically, your code looks fine given a cursory glance. Of course, perhaps the LINQ provider for CRM doesn't do this.

Comment: @alex yea it is CRM 2011

Comment: @Justin Are the values returned the same strings with different case? The comparer will be case-sensitive. Both your properties are strings on the anonymous type. Also, are they duplicate on both values?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I think you hit it on the head, i checked the ids and some reason they are different. So, same name, different ids. ack! Thanks!

Comment: @Justin Same name and different IDs is entirely possible - I'd be **considerably** more worried if it was the same ID and different names! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299412) call without an explicit comparer simply uses the default equality comparer, which in the case of anonymous types boils down to `Object.Equals`. This is overridden in anonymous types to be equal if all properties of the type are equal. In this case it will check the `AccountId` and `Account` properties.

I suspect this is working and that the values are different in terms of case (as strings compare case-sensitive by default) or they are in fact distinct and you just can't see it.

Luckily, it has nothing to do with the CRM-specific Linq provider.

Answer (score 1):

Use a specified `IEqualityComparer<T>`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356803

One other thing, I'm not sure if anonymous classes support the `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementations.

Comment: They do. The default comparer delegates to `Object.Equals` which is overridden on anonymous types to be equal if all properties are equal.